# What does =~ do in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators

I guess the tag is a variable, and it is checking for `9eaf` - but does this exist in Perl?

What is the "=~" sign doing here and what are the "/" characters before and after `9eaf` doing?

```
if ($tag =~ /9eaf/)
{
    # Do something
}
```

Comment: If you want to spend a few minutes learning about regular expressions in Perl have a look at [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

Comment: _Learning Perl_ explains it all :)

Comment: _This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet._ Quite the opposite.

Comment: `man perlop` "perlop - Perl operators and precedence" (at least in UNIX-like) answers this question: "Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match."

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`=~` is the operator testing a regular expression match. The expression `/9eaf/` is a regular expression (the slashes `//` are delimiters, the `9eaf` is the actual regular expression). In words, the test is saying "If the variable $tag matches the regular expression /9eaf/ ..." and this match occurs if the string stored in `$tag` contains those characters `9eaf` consecutively, in order, at any point. So this will be true for the strings

```
9eaf

xyz9eaf

9eafxyz

xyz9eafxyz
```

and many others, but not the strings

```
9eaxxx
9xexaxfx
```

and many others. Look up the ['perlre' man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information on regular expressions, or google "perl regular expression".

Comment: You mean if there is a space in between it does not work... for example... 9sssbt yyuuiihh 88880099 9eaf 888hhjjj nnmmmm. Will the above logic for this string???

Comment: No, `m//` is the <strike>operation</strike>operator testing the regex. `=~` simply tells `m//` (and `s///` and `tr//`) which variable to test against.

Comment: No, `/9eaf/` is not the regular expression. `/9eaf/` is the match operator. `9eaf` is the regular expression.

Answer (score 13):

The '=~' operator is a [binary binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) that indicates the following operation will search or modify the scalar on the left.

The default (unspecified) operator is 'm' for match.

The matching operator has a pair of characters that designate where the regular expression begins and ends.  Most commonly, this is '//'.

Give [Perl Re tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) a read.

Answer (score 10):

The code is testing whether `9eaf` is a substring of the value of `$tag`.

---

```
$tag =~ /9eaf/
```

is short for

```
$tag =~ m/9eaf/
```

where `m//` is the match operator. It matches the regular expression pattern (regexp) `9eaf` against the value bound by `=~` (returned by the left hand side of `=~`).

---

Operators, including `m//` and `=~`, are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Regular expressions (e.g. `9eaf`) are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 3):

That checks for a match of the scalar `$tag` (which is presumably a string) against the regular expression `/9eaf/`, which merely checks to see if the string `"9eaf"` is a substring of `$tag`.  Check out [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: You mean if there is a space in between it does not work... for example... 9sssbt yyuuiihh 88880099 9eaf 888hhjjj nnmmmm. Will the above logic for this string???

Comment: Why don't you try it for yourself?