# What does =~ mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What does =~ do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019049/what-does-this-do-in-perl)

In a Perl program I am examining (namly [plutil.pl](https://github.com/captn3m0/Scripts/blob/master/plutil.pl)), I see a lot of `=~` on the XML parser portion. For example, here is `UnfixXMLString` (lines `159` to `167` on 1.7):

```perl
sub UnfixXMLString {
    my ($s) = @_;

    $s =~ s/&lt;/</g;
    $s =~ s/&gt;/>/g;
    $s =~ s/&amp;/&/g;

    return $s;
}
```

From what I can tell, it's taking a string, modifying it with the `=~` operator, then returning that modified string, but what *exactly* is it doing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`=~` is the Perl [binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators). It's generally used to apply a regular expression to a string; for instance, to test if a string matches a pattern:

```
if ($string =~ m/pattern/) {
```

Or to extract components from a string:

```
my ($first, $rest) = $string =~ m{^(\w+):(.*)$};
```

Or to apply a substitution:

```
$string =~ s/foo/bar/;
```

Comment: More specifically, it’s used to bind a `m//`, `s///`, or `y///` (`tr///`) operator to a scalar.  Regexes are not involved for the last one.  It can also be used as `$var =~ $re`, which is pretty much the same as `$var =~ /$re/`.

Answer (score 5):

`=~` is the Perl binding operator and can be used to determine if a regular expression match occurred (true or false)

```
$sentence = "The river flows slowly.";
if ($sentence =~ /river/)
{
    print "Matched river.\n";
}
else
{
    print "Did not match river.\n";
}
```