# what does these perl variables mean?

Tags: perl, variables, coding-style, string-matching, slash

I'm a little noobish to perl coding conventions, could someone help explain:

- why are there `/` and `/<` in front of perl variables?
- what does`\=` and `=~` mean, and what is the difference?
- why does the code require an ending `/` before the `;`, e.g.    `/start=\'([0-9]+)\'/`?

**The 1st 3 sub-questions were sort of solved by really the perldocs, but what does the following line means in the code?**

`push(@{$Start{$start}},$features);`

**i understand that we are pushing the $features into a @Start array but what does `@$Start{$start}` mean? Is it the same as:**
`@Start = ($start);`

Within the code there is something like this:

```
use FileHandle;

sub open_infile {
  my $file = shift;
  my $in = FileHandle->new($file,"<:encoding(UTF-8)")
      or die "ERROR: cannot open $file: $!\n" if ($Opt_utf8);
  $in = new FileHandle("$file")
      or die "ERROR: cannot open $file: $!\n" if (!$Opt_utf8);
  return $in;
}

$uamf = shift @ARGV;
$uamin = open_infile($uamf);


while (<$uamin>) {
    chomp;
    if(/<segment /){
        /start=\'([0-9]+)\'/;
        /end=\'([0-9]+)\'/;
        /features=\'([^\']+)\'/;
        $features =~ s/annotation;//;

    push(@{$Start{$start}},$features); 
    push(@{$End{$end}},$features); 
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

So after some intensive reading of the perl doc, here's somethings i've gotten

- The `/<segment /` is a regex check that checks whether the readline
  in `while (<$uamin>)` contains the following string: `<segment`.
- Similarly the `/start=\'([0-9]+)\'/` has nothing to to do with
  instantiating any variable, it's a regex check to see whether the
  readline in `while (<$uamin>)` contains `start=\'([0-9]+)\'` which
  `\'([0-9]+)\'` refers to a numeric string.
- In `$features =~ s/annotation;//` the `=~` is use because the string
  replacement was testing a regular expression match. See
  [What does =~ do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019049/what-does-this-do-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you see this syntax (or more to the point: have you edited stuff out of what you saw)?  `/foo/` represents the match operator using regular expressions, not variables.  In other words, the first line is checking to see if the input string `$_` contains the character sequence `<segment`.

The subsequent three lines essentially do nothing useful, in the sense that they run regular expression matches and then discard the results (there are side-effects, but subsequent regular expressions discard the side-effects, too).

The last line does a substitution, replacing the first occurance of the characters `annotation;` with the empty string in the string `$features`.

Run the command [perldoc perlretut](http://p3rl.org/retut) to learn about regex in Perl.

Comment: i've yet edited the code. do you that the 1st line checks if the inputstrng $_ contains the character "<segment" instead of ">segment"?