# Perl =~ operator in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm "translating" perl script to C# and I came across this operator: =~

Is there anything similar in C#?

It's my first time with perl, so it's pretty much a shot in the dark.

Thanks

Comment: `=~` is a matching operator

Comment: That's a regex thing isn't it? If so, use the RegEx library.

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(...)`

Comment: Depending on what's on the right side you might also be able to use `string` methods instead of `Regex`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a reasonable question and not at all one of those "translate my Perl code to C# for me" questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Regex.IsMatch` should be same as `=~` in Perl. As I read from the below article its just a regular expression match.

[What does =~ do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019049/what-does-do-in-perl)

Comment: Thank you very much